# How to discover which application installed a font?

Tags: windows-7

I have some commercial fonts installed I never buyed.
Some application I use certainly installed them for me and I'm grateful about that.

As I'm getting addicted to some of those, I'd like to know which package did it.
(So in the future I maybe can get them free and legal on other computers)

Is there any *standard installation **receipt*** mechanisms in Win7 (like, more or less, that in *OSX*) telling you which "package" installed a file, or... no such thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general mechanism for discovering which application installed a font on Windows. However, here are some tips that might help you find this out.

1. Open the list of fonts in Control Panel. Right-click on a font and select properties. If the font was installed directly from the application's directory, you'll see that in `Location` field there. However, if the font was moved to `C:\Windows\Fonts`, you're out of luck.
2. Search the registry for the name of font or its file name. Some installers record what they installed in the registry. So, run `regedt`, press <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> and search, it will take a long time.

But if some application just copied a TTF file into `C:\Windows\Fonts`, there's no sure way to know which one did that.

Comment: You could look at the modified date on the TTF file and then search in C:\Program Files\ for any other files modified on that date. The EXE of any likely source program will probably have the same modified date.